# Why do bid estimates fluctuate so much?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I'm currently working with the Reach Estimates of the Facebook Ads API, detailed here -

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate/

I ran a test to measure the change in a number of bid estimates at an interval of 20 - 30 seconds. Looking at the CPC max values, many of the changes between queries were between +/- 5%, and some changed by up to +/- 14%.

I understand that these are estimates, but can anyone give an insight into the rapid fluctuations in these bid estimates, and recommend strategies to overcome these fluctuations?